# MongoDB and C# datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with C# driver. I managed to add/delete/update data from collections, but I dont know how to display a collection in the gridview. If it's not possible, how can I display collections as tables in asp.net?

Comment: Which C# driver are you using?

Comment: I'll try a few things today with that driver.

Comment: So where is problem? You can't get collection from mongodb or you can't bind List of some date to gridview, or both?

Comment: I guess my question is what is a best way to do that, so you say, what I should grab data from MongoDB, convert it to to the List and then use it for a gridview?

Comment: Just look at my answer! Hope this help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First load a query from mongodb like this:

```
      var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27020");
      var database = server.GetDatabase("someDb");

      var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("someCollection");
      var searchQuery = Query.EQ("someName", "someValue"); // you can place any search condition here 
      //if you want all documents from collection use FindAll
      var cursor = collection.Find(searchQuery);
      cursor.SetLimit(50); // you can specify limit
      // set sort orders
    cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("someSorField").Descending("someSorField2"));

    var resultList = cursor.ToList(); //get list of items from mongodb
```

Then on Page_Load event, bind data:

```
 gvwExample.DataSource = resultList;
 gvwExample.DataBind();
```

Then specify binding to datasource on the page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwExample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="basix" >
<columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: what is DataField="FirstName"